# OpenGL or Canvas for Paint Application on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I am beginning to write a finger paint style application (I have seen the tutorial on the Google Developer resource). The application will have the following:

1.) A background image to paint on top of

2.) When drawing with finger, it will not draw colors, but a texture/image like a photoshop brush.

I have begun the implementation in OpenGL but am running into an issue with creating many quads during a finger drag. I was wondering if anyone had some pointers that can lead me to decide if I should continue writing in OpenGL or to scrap and go to Canvas? What are the advantages and disadvantages, as well as restrictions for an application like this.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Personally I would go for Canvas. For this kind of application it might be best to use offscreen FBO as render target where you render only new textures on top of existing ones. But when it comes to handling this output texture - say saving it as an image or user is navigating back and forth from your application - Canvas/Bitmap may turn much easier to handle.

Comment: Interesting feedback. The FBO may not work as the user would need to see paint as their finger is dragging. I am also looking into a way to paint a texture onto an existing quad, but it seems I would need Texture subregions with a lot of calculating for this.

Comment: Using one fullscreen FBO should not be an issue if I understand your goal correctly. You can add new textured quads incrementally to it - and render it as a whole to screen buffer. But this depends very much on how these quads ought to be added in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest OpenGL. Maby harder but it will be much better for you in future when you will need more from your app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you both but for painting you should use Canvas but if you want also edit and add effects you need OpenGL.